# Why doesn't scala do type checking when checking for equality

Tags: scala

For example:

```
scala> val a: String = "5"
a: String = 5

scala> val b: Int = 5
b: Int = 5

scala> a == b
res5: Boolean = false
```

I expect a TypeError, like in Java:

```
class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        int a = 5;
        String b = "5";
        System.out.println(a == b);
    }
}
```

I wonder what was the reasoning of `scala` designers to not doing type checking. I personally don't see any advantage of not doing it. When could it be practically useful? However, it could lead to run time bugs.

Also, I feel, that stronger type checking is more inline with functional paradigm, why did `scala` changed that behavior of its predecessor `java`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scala inherited this behavior from Java.

The key is that Scala's `==` is equivalent to Java's `equals`, not `==` (which checks referential equality).

Comment: Is the following statement correct? : Scala inherited equals from Java; equals in Scala act the same as Java. But Scala designers decided to use == to call equals instead of doing using == for referential equality.

Comment: @Akavall yes, that's essentially correct

Answer (score 2):

Scala inherited the concept of universal equality from its host languages. Remember, Scala is designed to be a *hosted language*, i.e. a language that becomes part of another language's ecosystem. For example, the (now abandoned) Scala.NET on the .NET platform, Scala-JVM on the Java platform, Scala.js on the ECMAScript platform, and so on.

What all of those languages have in common, is universal equality:

```java
// ### Java:
String s = "42";
int    i =  42;


// ### Value equality:
s.equals(i);
//=> false


// ### Reference equality:
s == i
// error: bad operand types for binary operator '=='
```

```csharp
// ### C♯:
var s = "42";
var i =  42;

// ### Value equality:
s.Equals(i);
//=> False

s == i;
// error CS0019: Operator `==' cannot be applied to operands of type `string' and `int'


// ### Reference equality:
object.ReferenceEquals(s, i);
//=> False
```

```ecmascript
// ### ECMAScript:
const s = "42";
const i =  42;

// ### Value equality:
s == i;
//=> true

s === i;
//=> false
```

```scala
// ### Scala:
val s = "42"
val i =  42

// ### Value equality:
s == i
//=> false


// ### Reference equality:
s eq i
// error: the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef
```

As you can see, Scala is not alone in returning a boolean for value equality. Java, C♯ (except when using the `==` operator), and ECMAScript behave similarly. (ECMAScript even returns `true` in one case!)

There *are*, however, people in the Scala community who [think hard about equality](http://typelevel.org/blog/2017/04/02/equivalence-vs-equality.html). Thankfully, they don't only complain, they also offer solutions, for example, [Scalaz](http://Scalaz.org/)'s [`Equal`](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/snapshots/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.12/7.3.0-SNAPSHOT/scalaz_2.12-7.3.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar/!/scalaz/Equal.html) typeclass and [cats](http://typelevel.org/cats/)' [`Eq`](http://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/kernel/Eq.html) typeclass are not universal.

Comment: Is the following statement correct? : Scala inherited `equals` from Java; `equals` in Scala act the same as Java. But Scala designers decided to use `==` to call `equals` instead of doing using `==` for referential equality.